# Testing the bot in Web Chat does not return the reply. The Bot is returning a 503 error

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Bot Info

SDK Platform: Nodejs

SDK Version: 3.14.0

Active Channels: Webchat, Directline
Deployment Environment: Bot Channels Registration, Azure App Service
Bot Handle: TB12

Issue Description
Bot is not able to respond back, throwing "503 Service Unavailable".

URL
The bot is live at http://testst.bombeohq.com/

Reproduction Steps

The bot is supposed to send a proactive message to begin the conversation, after which the user replies with "I will like to sell a house", and the rest of the dialogflow is initiated.

I thought this was an issue with my code, but I experienced the same 503 error with the bot not responding back to messages sent.

Comment: Add a minimal code example of your problem

Comment: added a snippet of the code in the entry point (app.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because it appears you are not using any [state storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). For testing, you can use [in-memory storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#in-memory-data-storage). But since it is volatile and temporary, this should only be used for testing. Additionally, the [Bot State Service](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/) has been retired and is [no longer an option](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/02/reminder-the-bot-framework-state-service-has-been-retired-what-you-need-to-know/). You can use other state storage options such as [Azure CosmoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) and [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).